# Recursively preform a function on list values and store each result in Python

Tags: python, list, function, recursion

I have some ugly code that does what I want to do, which is preform a function "x // 3 - 2" on each value in a list until that value is 0 (and store the result each time to add up later), but I want to modify it to serve hundreds of list values instead of just these three.

```
fuellist = []
modules = [14, 1969, 100756]
def getfuel(lst):
  newlist = [x // 3 - 2 for x in lst]
  for x in newlist:
    if x < 0:
      newlist.remove(x)
  return newlist


list1 = getfuel(modules)
list2 = getfuel(list1)
list3 = getfuel(list2)
list4 = getfuel(list3)
list5 = getfuel(list4)
list6 = getfuel(list5)
list7 = getfuel(list6)
list8 = getfuel(list7)
list9 = getfuel(list8)
list10 = getfuel(list9)

total = list1 + list2 + list3 + list4 + list5 + list6 + list7 + list8 + list9 + list10
print(sum(total))
```

The output is/should be for this list: 51314

I can't remember the best way to go about it. I've tried using a while loop but it gets caught in some kind of infinite loop. I'm not sure if "recursive" is the right word for what I'm looking for either, I wish I could explain it better. Thanks for your help.

Comment: " I've tried using a while loop but it gets caught in some kind of infinite loop.": so that is more of an actual, practical problem, but you don't show that code. Probably, that is the code (and question) you'd like to be answered.

Comment: For suggestions on improving code, you may be better off at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a while loop if an list is empty it get evaluated to false so

```
modules = [14, 1969, 100756]
def getfuel(lst):
    result = 0
    while lst:
        lst = [x for x in [x // 3 - 2 for x in lst] if x > 0]
        result+=sum(lst)
    return result

print(getfuel(modules)) # returns the sum
```

Comment: This returns 45647, but the sum in the original is 51314.

Comment: fixed it wrong identation for return result thanks for your feedback

Comment: No need for `first` and the duplication of the complex list comprehension. Just loop on `while lst` and re-assing `lst` itself.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. I haven't seen a list comprehension in a list comprehension, and I like the succinct aspect of it.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my answer after you commented. This will work just fine for you. It's a pretty simple and easy to understand approach to the problem.

```py
fuellist = []
modules = [14, 1969, 100756]
def getfuel(lst):
  newlist = [x // 3 - 2 for x in lst]
  for x in newlist:
    if x < 0:
      newlist.remove(x)
  return newlist

l = [getfuel(modules)]
for i in range(10):
    l.append(getfuel(l[i]))
s = 0
for i in l:
    s += sum(i)
print(s)
```

When you remove an element, it gets removed from the list but the `for loop` gets it's termination value at the initial run, so even if you change the list content later in the loop, it would still run till where you had set it initially, so it ends up showing an error or goes for an infinite loop.
Hope it solves your problem :)

Comment: This is not really what I was looking for. The problem I have is not being able to store each result of the getfuel function in an effective way. I'm sure my function could be improved, but this doesn't appear to help me with my problem.

Comment: @ckrug I have made the necessary changes. I didn't much change your code and tried to keep it as simple as possible. Let me know if you have any confusions. Cheers :)